# MIPS, why this branch doesn't work?

Tags: arrays, branch, mips

I have to do a `bne` taking one argument from an array declared pp: .space 40, in that array i put integer, 0 or 1, it's a flag.
But whatever I do, the `bne`never work! How I have to pass the argument??

```
li $s5, 0
li $t1, 10
la $s0, pp # address 
la $s1, nome # address 
la $s2, cognome # address 
la $s3, interessi # address 
la $s4, userid # address

looplista:
beq $s5, $t1, exit

# check flag


printarray:
lw $t2, 0($s0) 


li $t0, 0
bne $t0, $t2, SALTO
```

How i store

```
la $s1, pp

mul $t2, $s7, 4
add $s1, $s1, $t2      #s7=0 array size counter

# prompt for name
li      $v0, 4
la      $a0, ppdom          
syscall                         #ask name

# store name (max 4 bytes) to pp_array ($s1)  
move $a0, $s1
li      $a1, 4
li      $v0, 5
syscall
```

Comment: How do you put the value (0 or 1) into the pp array ?

Comment: la $s1, pp
 
 mul $t2, $s7, 4
    add $s1, $s1, $t2      #s2=0 array size counter
 
 # prompt for name
    li      $v0, 4
    la      $a0, ppdom          
    syscall                         #ask name

    # store name (max 4 bytes) to str_array ($s1)  
    move $a0, $s1
    li      $a1, 4
    li      $v0, 5
    syscall

Comment: Put the code in the question, the comment is not understandable

Comment: Do you need more information?

Comment: After you load $s1 with pp you are adding something to $s1 ($s7 * 4), so are probably storing the input  in some other address (not pp)

Comment: But I use this code for store strings and it work correctly, and pp is an array, I have to scroll it. Whit strings it print the correct data, whit int it print 0, ever 0, but can't use it for the bne

Comment: I think you will have to debug your code (e.g. using MARS debugger). You show only some pieces and we cant guess what code is in your gaps.

Comment: I debugged; At the instruction la $s0, pp the address is 10010960, the same at the la $s1, pp of the store code section.. but in the User data segment i can see where i stored s2,s3,s4,s5 but not s0, i can't see 10010960, i stored 1 in the pp position, but it load 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem, read int function return the valor in `$v0`, I used `$a0`

```
la $s1, pp

mul $t2, $s7, 4      #s7=0 array size counter

# prompt for name
li      $v0, 4
la      $a0, ppdom          
syscall                         #ask 

li $v0, 5
syscall
sw $v0, pp($t2)
```